# What did the lawn chair complain of?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> A drink I do take,
>   to calm all my shakes,
>   and heave a sigh of relief.
>
> The moon dims and fades,
>   then once again shines,
>   glimmering on that which fells trees.
>
> A little flutter,
>   and now I do stutter,
>   my tongue swollen red, green and blue.
>
> Good for the skin,
>   making it pearly and new,
>   as long as you pay heed
>   to whispers in the breeze,
>   that humming sound that drives you mad,
>   and the reason I am here alone.
>
> -From, a lawn chair in the sun

to what is this letter referring? Why do you think the lawn chair is alone?

Notes:
Well, Easy Tiger figure out one part of the riddle, at least: The lawn chair is complaining that it's lonely. However, he is not quite right on WHY the owner has...shall we say...disappeared.

Also, keep in mind that every Stanza refers to a separate object that, when combined together, creates a story explaining what the lawn chair is complaining of. Listed below is the hints for each, as well as how the particular part of the story occurred, by way of an event that ties in to the particular object in question.

Stanza 1:

> A drink I am sharing, with buscuits a latte. Tho others might pour a bit of **ME** in their___(rhymes if pronounced with the right accent).  EVENT: SPILL/POUR

Stanza 2:

> the answer is hidden yet there in plain sight, (these words repeated X times 'fore the fight). EVENT: VERB IN THE STANZA

Stanza 3:

> If I had cleared a Tin, I would be able to see; but, until then, my nose stays stuffy. EVENT: "TRIGGERED"

Stanza 4:

> First two lines help to explain why this event occured. The rest is a warning to not repeat the same mistakes. EVENT: WHY?

Answer (score 6):

The answer could be -

> The Lawn Chair is alone because the trees have been cut down to make paper.

This is what the poem means.

> - The first stanza is referring to a printer with RGB ink.
>   - The second stanza refers to refilling ink in the printer.
>   - The third stanza describes the action of scanning in a photocopier machine (made by cutting down trees = "which fells trees"). Both the printer and photocopier use paper (and hence trees).
>   - The fourth stanza refers to a tissue ("making the skin pearly and new"). The sound of tree-leaves in wind = "whispers in the breeze".

Comment: Good start, but not quite. The answer *is* associated with trees.

Comment: No printers use (only) RGB ink.  That wouldn't allow them to reproduce a full spectrum of colours (e.g. yellow).

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Uhh...R, G, and B can be combined to form any color in the spectrum. -sorry, just geeking out here.-

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I know that contemporary printer use CMYK instead of RGB but I just thought RGB made sense in the puzzle.

Comment: @Nyk232 That is (mostly) true when you're talking about light, but when you're talking about ink, it is patently untrue.

Comment: uhh, I thought Ink was like any other type of paint, but I guess I was wrong...

Comment: Paints/inks use [subtractive color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_color), not additive color.

Answer (score 6):

My guess:

> The Lawn Chair is alone because its previous occupant was squashed by a tree.

My thinking:

A drink I do take,
to calm all my shakes,
and heave a sigh of relief.

> I'd like to think of this as a rainstorm filling and settling a lawn chair buffeted by the wind.  Alternatively, 'the shakes' could gruesomely refer to moment the owner violently had a tree dropped on them.

The moon dims and fades,
then once again shines,
glimmering on that which fells trees.

> The chair can still see the chainsaw, presumably dropped after the accident occurred.

A little flutter,
and now I do stutter,
my tongue swollen red, green and blue.

> The best I can do here is the tongue is the fabric part of the chair.  The red = the blood stains, the green = grass/leaf stains, and the blue = maybe it was a blue chair originally?

Good for the skin,
making it pearly and new,
as long as you pay heed
to whispers in the breeze,
that humming sound that drives you mad,
and the reason I am here alone.

> Sitting in the shade of a huge tree is a great way to avoid sunburn, provided you make sure that the annoying humming noise isn't actually your neighbour cutting down the tree with a chainsaw.

Comment: Well, you got the first part right. The chair is all alone now, but not because it's owner was squashed by the tree!

Answer (score 0):

What I think:

> Deforestation ---> Resource Depletion

Why?

Stanza 2:

> Using the phrase "fells trees" hints that trees were cut down and now light shines where they would have been

Stanza 3:

> Could be referring to a chainsaw which makes fluttering noises when it starts and has a "tongue" which is pulled to start its engine

Stanza 4:

> Certain oils can be extracted from trees i.e. shea butter. Paying heed to the whispers in the breeze could refer to the sounds of leaves in the wind and that we need to pay respect/ attention to trees. Humming could again refer to a chainsaw.

In closing:

> Deforestation which can eventually cause a decrease in the CO2 to breathable oxygen conversion which could lead to the extinction of humanity. The lack of trees which will cause the lack of humans (a lawn chair's best friend) is why the lawn chair is alone.

Answer (score 0):

The chair is mourning its owner who

> was stung to death by a swarm of bees

Stanza 1

> The woodcutter drinks something that may alleviate the pain of the numerous stings.

Stanza 2

> The woodcutter had bothered a hive of wild bees that was in the tree he was cutting. The swarm darkens the sky while diving onto the poor man. Once the swarm has left, the moon shines on his axe / his chainsaw that felt on the ground.

Stanza 3

> The last hiccups of a dying man. The bee stings have swollen and colored his flesh.

Stanza 4

> Not sure what exactly is good for the skin, maybe an allusion to bee-venom therapy. The humming sound is that of a bee swarm which may have been covered by the running chainsaw.